# Can kafka connect use topics as source then sink it to another topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is just a silly question i made, but i'm really curious about have anyone here create a kafka connector sink with topic as his destination.

The flow will become like this, **topic a -> connector -> topic b**. Or is there any suggestion so i can make it running like that?

Answer (score 2):

This is how both [MirrorMaker 2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-RunningMirrorMakerinaConnectcluster) and [Replicator](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-replicator) from Confluent work. They're designed for inter-cluster replication of topics, but I guess there's no reason you couldn't use them for intra-cluster.